# Función filter no devuelve ningún valor

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo a usar la función `filter` pero no me devuelve lo que yo esperaba.

```
def es_par(n):
    if n % 2.0 == 0:
        print(n, "True")
        return True
    else:
        print("False", n)
        return


lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = filter(es_par, lista)
print(l2)
```

Cuando hago `print(l2)` me devuelve:

> filter object at 0x000000000B2E7908

En lugar de los números pares.

Supongo que estoy haciendo algo mal, pero no sé el qué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En python3 muchas de las funciones de programación funcional como `map()`, `filter()`, etc. no devuelven listas, sino generadores.

De ese modo la evaluación es "lazy", esto es, el filtro no es ejecutado hasta que no se necesite realmente porque estés iterando sobre los resultados. Al iterar, entonces sí, se irá ejecutando el filtro, un elemento cada vez, para cada iteración.

La ventaja de una evaluación "lazy" es que requiere menos memoria (pues no tiene que construir la lista con el resultado sino que va devolviendo un elemento de cada vez), además de permitir la creación de generadores y filtros capaces de operar sobre listas potencialmente infinitas.

De hecho, en tu código, verás que la función `es_par()` no llega a ejecutarse ni una vez, pues los `print()` que contiene no llegan a verse por pantalla. Para que se ejecute tienes que iterar sobre el filtro. Por ejemplo así:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = filter(es_par, lista)
for elemento in l2:
  print(elemento)
```

```
False 1
2 True
2
False 3
4 True
4
False 5
6 True
6
```

Ahí puedes ver entremezclados los `print()` que hace la función `es_par()` y el `print(elemento)` del bucle.

Otra forma de forzar la ejecución del filtro es convertirlo en una lista. Internamente python iterará sobre el filtro e irá añadiendo cada resultado a una lista, para retornarte finalmente la lista resultante:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = list(filter(es_par, lista))
```

```
False 1
2 True
False 3
4 True
False 5
6 True
```

Vemos los `print()` que hacía tu función, pues al convertir el filtro en lista e iterar sobre él se va llamando. Ahora `l2` será una lista con el resultado:

```
>>> print(l2)
[2, 4, 6]
```

(**Nota**. Esto no era así en python2, en el que los operadores funcionales retornaban listas, si estabas leyendo alguna documentación con ejemplos para python2, tendrás que adaptarlos)

#### Actualización

Un último detalle. Cualquier cosa que puedas hacer con programación funcional (`map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()`) puedes lograrlo también con *comprensiones de listas* (*list comprehensions*) y para muchos (incluído Guido, creador de Python) la sintaxis es mucho más clara.

En tu caso, para filtrar los elementos pares con esta sintaxis sería:

```
l2 = [e for e in lista if e%2 == 0]
```

Esto sí te da una lista. Si prefieres un generador (lazy), cambia los corchetes por paréntesis:

```
>>> l2 = (e for e in lista if e%2 == 0)
>>> print(l2)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1f2e4e3308>
>>> for e in l2: print(e)
2
4
6
```

Ten en cuenta no obstante que una vez que un generador llega a su fin, "se agota". Si intentas de nuevo un `for e in l2` ya no obtendrás elementos. Si vas a necesitar usarlos más veces será mejor tenerlos en una lista.

Comment: Efectivamente, estoy siguiendo documentación de python2. Entonces, en python3, la función `filter()` por sí sola ¿no tiene ninguna utilidad?¿siempre es necesario aplicarle una iteración para que trabaje?

Comment: La utilidad es la misma que en python2, pero funciona de forma "lazy", devolviéndote los elementos al iterar. Si quieres tener el mismo resultado que en python2, basta poner un `list()` alrededor, como en el último ejemplo de mi respuesta.

Comment: @Zhisi Por cierto, que `range()` es otra de las funciones que ha pasado de devolver una lista (python2) a un generador (python3). Python2 tenía también `xrange()`, que se comporta como el `range()` de python3 (quien, por tanto, no tiene `xrange()`). Cuidado con los ejemplos que te encuentres.

Comment: @Zhisi He actualizado la respuesta para explicar otra sintaxis, más pythónica y que la mayoría de los programadores prefiere.

Comment: ¿Y si no me interesa tener una lista con todos los datos generados, pero sí que me interesa el último dato? Por ejemplo si quiero sumar una lista de datos. @abulafia

Comment: Si no quieres la lista entera, aún así tienes que generar todos los elementos anteriores para llegar al último. Por ejemplo: `for e in generador: dato=e`. Cuando ese bucle termine, `dato` tendrá el valor del último elemento. No obstante no entiendo lo que dices de sumar una lista, ya que para eso necesitas todos los elementos y no sólo el último. La función `sum()` vale también sobre generadores, esto es, `sum(generador)` iterará sobre todos los elementos del generador, y te devolverá la suma de todos ellos (sin necesidad de crear una lista intermedia). @Zhisi

Comment: Perdona, mi anterior mensaje no tiene mucho sentido.